Correlating IP and/or hostname to physical location
I have a large number of Raspberry Pis (~1000) that I need all in the same cluster.  Is there a (somewhat automated) way to correlate physical location of each Pi to an IP address or hostname, or to assign an IP address or hostname based on physical location?  For example, the first physical device in the cluster will be hostname: rasp0001 and the second will be hostname: rasp0002 and so on.
I will have to add a custom hat to each, so I could do something like add a pushbutton to each hat so that a user could push the button of each hat in sequence to help identify the physical location.  What I am not sure about is how to then change the hostname of each to iterate based on the sequence of pushed buttons.
This is just one idea, but open to any good ideas or advice.

You specify IP by "physical location" but your sequential numbering doesn't allow for a Pi to not be working when you're bringing up the cluster.  With 1000 Pi, hardware problems will be 1000 times more likely than with one Pi.  Having 1000 Pi in one cluster suggests to me that you will need special powering (PoE?) and interconnect (Ethernet) switches. Look into tagging a physical location in PoE hat or through Ethernet switch port.

There are probably a multitude of ways of accomplishing what you want to achieve. Examining your approach first:
Button-on-a-hat
If I understand correctly, you want your button press (on an already booted Pi) to cause the Pi to change its IP address (and hostname) to a sequential number that follows the number of the "last  Pi” (i.e. most  recent) to have its “button-on-a-hat” pressed. Presumably, this button-on-a-hat is just connected to a GPIO input pin.
So, essentially, each RPi node has a polled GPIO input that, when triggered, causes the Pi to query and determine what the next IP address should be and reconfigure itself with that IP address, using raspi-config (or some other method).
You could manually trigger an input (i.e. press a “button-on-a-hat”) on each of the RPi nodes at intervals of one minute (or so1), which then causes the RPi to query an ordering server - another device that holds a record of the current (i.e. last requested) order number by a RPi node (i.e. an order client).
This ordering server would be a third party PC/RPi that holds the number of the current Pi in the overall order of IP address setting. It could take the form of a text file or a simple database, that just holds an integer value between 1 and 1000 (or however many nodes you have in your cluster.
The simplest (and most insecure) way to achieve this would be a  remote text file with read/write permissions on an RSH host with .rhosts containing a +. Then, when their button-on-a-hat is pressed, the individual Pi nodes can query this file, retrieve the number, increment it, set their IP address and hostname accordingly and then and update the file as appropriate.
Assuming an ordering server, with hostname of ordersrv, holds the current order number in a file /order.txt. The following script would be run on a node Pi to query the ordering server:
# Read and output to local file
rsh ordersrv cat /order.txt > previousOrderNumber.txt
# Get the previous order number
mynum=`cat previousOrderNumber.txt`
# Increment the previous order number
mynum = `expr $mynum + 1
# Write and update remote file with the new current order number
rsh ordersrv /order.txt < echo $mynum 
# Change Pi node's IP address and hostname
...  # raspi-config

or
# Read, increment and output to local file
rsh ordersrv echo `expr \`cat /order.txt\` + 1` > myOrderNumber.txt
# Get the current order number
mynum=`cat myOrderNumber.txt`
# Read, increment and update remote file
rsh ordersrv "expr `cat /order.txt 2>/dev/null` + 1 >/order.txt"
# Change Pi node's IP address and hostname
...  # raspi-config

or just
# Read, increment and update remote file
rsh ordersrv "expr `cat /order.txt 2>/dev/null` + 1 >/order.txt"
# Read and output to local file
rsh ordersrv cat /order.txt > myOrderNumber.txt
# Get the current order number
mynum=`cat myOrderNumber.txt`
# Change Pi node's IP address and hostname
...  # raspi-config

Of course, you should use SSH, rather than RSH, to make this more secure - I'm only using RSH as a simple example.
A more sophisticated method would be to have the Pi node query a similar ordering server running a Python listener port, and that server reads the file locally (to itself) and replies to the querying Pi node with an updated (i.e. incremented) integer, and writes that integer back to its local file/database.
Of course, once the client has received its ID, it will need to work out its IP address. Obviously, if you have a class C network, there can only be 254 nodes per subnet. So, if you have one thousand, then you'll need to have several subnets, or move to a class B network (which supports 65,534 hosts)
Once all of the 1000 nodes in the cluster have been configured correctly, or in the event of a botched or partial configuration, it is important to remember to reset the order number to zero on the order server, before running another IP address configuration process.
So, in the example above, you would need to write a zero to the file /orderNumber.txt. Run this script on the ordering server:
# Reset order server
cat 0 > /orderNumber.txt

Problems

It is not guaranteed that current Pi has actually read and updated the remote order file, before the next button is pressed, on the next Pi in the sequence.
It would be annoying and repetitive to have to hit a button on each Pi, and at what frequency or time interval between presses?
Whatever time interval, it will be annoying to have to press one thousand buttons, every one minute or so1.
You have to write a server client application, or have an insecure RSH server on the network. OK, you could use SSH, but either way, there is a requirement for an additional server - and all of what that entails (maintenance, etc.)
The combination of the manual work required along with the janky remote file and book-keeping, and scripting required seem to make this option not very attractive and possibly awkward or difficult to maintain.


Here are a couple of alternative ways:
Sequential IP address via DHCP server
Instead of sequentially "hitting a button on a hat", you could simply manually turn on each of the devices, at roughly one minute intervals (or so2), in an order that (somehow3) correlates to their location, and have DHCP server set up in such a way that the IP addresses are leased in a sequential order (and the server disregards the DHCP clients' MAC addresses).
So, as an example, for a pool of addresses 192.168.100.1/24, each Pi would be assigned in order of being powered on (assuming 192.168.100.1 is for the master or DHCP server/gateway):
192.168.100.2
192.168.100.3
192.168.100.4
192.168.100.5
...
192.168.100.254

Obviously for a cluster of 1000 nodes you would need to either use multiple DHCP lease pools or adjust the network settings (i.e. larger subnets).
The IP address to hostname mapping would (presumably) be done by DNS, so that (hopefully) automatically takes care of the hostname (assuming that the hostname is provided by DHCP to the DHCP client).
Obviously, you would have to manually craft the DNS table (or Host table for each node, if you skip on the DNS), to include entries for each node (using the same addresses as the above example - adjust if necessary):
192.168.100.2  rasp0001
192.168.100.3  rasp0002
192.168.100.4  rasp0003
192.168.100.5  rasp0004
...

You could script the generation of this file - after all, it doesn't depend upon, or change with, the physical location of the device.
Problems

It will be annoying and repetitive to have to turn on each Pi in order of “location”, every minute (or so1) in the same way that hitting a button on a hat on one thousand nodes would be.
Similar to the button-on-the-hat approach, this method shares a lot of the similar problems
The requirement of the manual labour (switching on 1000 nodes at time intervals) and a specifically configured DHCP server also makes this approach tiresome

Use PXE boot and MAC address mapping
Assuming that you know the MAC addresses, and the physical location, of each of the Pi devices, then you could just keep a file containing a table of MAC addresses against IP address and manually maintain that table so that the MAC addresses have an IP address that corresponds to the IP address that you desire that location to have. You could even have a "location" column that just serves as an aide-mémoire, and whose data isn't ever used "digitally":



IP address
MAC
Location




192.168.1.1
a1:b1:c1:d1:e1:f1
Top of stack1


192.168.1.2
a2:b2:c2:d2:e2:f2
Middle of stack1


192.168.1.3
a3:b3:c3:d3:e3:f3
Bottom of stack1


192.168.1.4
a4:b4:c4:d4:e4:f4
Top of stack2


...
...
...



In other words, you have a file that maps IP address to location, via the MAC address of the Pi at that location.
Once you have that, then you can configure a PXE server with all of the respectively cluster nodes' disk images configured appropriately (with hostname and IP address), on one of the Pi devices designated as a master. Now you can power the devices on in any order, and each node will get their respective boot image, according to their MAC address, from the master node - with the correct IP address and hostname already assigned.
Something similar to this answer to Running a cluster of 65 Raspberry Pis with one SD Card (is it possible?)
Problems

None really.
IMHO, this is the easiest and most maintainable option.


Useful resources

How to increment number in a file
The Five IPv4 Classes - Quick Reference
.rhosts File Format for TCP/IP
Commands from Remote Shell: rsh

Footnotes
1 Depending upon how long it takes for a cluster node Pi to start up and request an order number from the ordering server.
2 Depending upon how long takes to start up and request an IP address from the DHCP server.
3 Presumably, if you have a stack of ten Pi in a rack, with a "location" of "1" at the top and "10" at the bottom, then you would power them on starting with number "1" through to "10".
